# make multicore (-j) does not handle dependencies correctly?

Tags: makefile, multicore

I have a makefile with this line:

```
parser_yacc.h parser_yacc.c :   parser_yacc.y
    bison -y -d parser_yacc.y && mv y.tab.h parser_yacc.h && \
            mv y.tab.c parser_yacc.c
```

now I have several other lines that depend on parser_yacc.h. When I perform `make` everything runs fine. However when I run `make -j4` I always get this warning:

```
mv: cannot stat `y.tab.c': No such file or directory
```

As I understand make tries to build both `parser_yacc.c` and another file that needs `parser_yacc.h`at the same time; thus spawning twice the commands

```
bison -y -d parser_yacc.y && mv y.tab.h parser_yacc.h && \
    mv y.tab.c parser_yacc.c
```

causing the second to crash... How could I circumvent this problem?

Comment: make doesn't understand that the same command builds both of those target files. You need to use a pattern rule to get make to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might rewrite the rule for either of the targets alone (e.g. the .c), and add another rule for completing the other one.

```
parser_yacc.c :   parser_yacc.y
    bison -y -d parser_yacc.y && mv y.tab.c parser_yacc.c

parser_yacc.h : parser_yacc.c
    mv y.tab.h parser_yacc.h
```

Comment: I've been messing around a little and came up with something similar. looks good :) tx